# How can I migrate legacy passwords to SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I have a legacy system which is getting rebuilt in MVC4.  I understand how to connect SimpleMembership to my 'users' table, but I'm not sure how to import my existing passwords into the webpages_Membership table (in particular with regard to the password encoding).

How can I migrate my legacy passwords to the new SimpleMembership 'way' ?  If possible, I'd like to do this all via SQL code.

Thanks!

Comment: There are breadcrumbs for you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236533/migrating-from-asp-net-membership-to-simplemembership-in-mvc4-rtm

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen that, but since my app doesn't have an "old-style" membership password, it didn't seem to totally apply, unless its possible to make it work with some other scenarios.  I'll look into that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm going to do:

I'm going to add a "temporary password" column to my "Users" table.  On failed login via the standard membership lookup ( `WebSecurity.Login()` ), I will perform an extra lookup on my "Users" table to match the "UserName" and the "temporary password" with the entered credentials.  If I find a match there, then I'll use the WebSecurity methods to create the appropriate membership records, including roles.  After successful creation, I'll delete the temporary password.