# Simplemembership Provider ASP.NET MVC 4 Password Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have moved along nicely migrating to simplemembership. The only thing that is hanging me up now is how do I configure password settings such as whether it's hashed, clear, or encrypted, etc. I don't believe it will be in the web.config any longer.

Comment: if this is not possible how would I go about retrieving passwords. If someone could just point me in the right direction..

Comment: You can't retrieve passwords with SimpleMembership.  There is no workaround.  You must use some other membership provider, such as the standard SqlMembershipProvider.

Comment: Encrypt it the way you want in the database. When creating a user, encrypt the password before saving. When authenticating, encrypt the user supplied password and match against your db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemembership is Designed around a specific view of users, roles and profiles

The existing providers are focused on traditional membership - a user has a username and a password, some specific roles on the site (e.g. administrator, premium user), and may have some additional "nice to have" optional information that can be accessed via an API in your application.

This doesn't fit well with some modern usage patterns:

In OAuth and OpenID, the user doesn't have a password
Often these kinds of scenarios map better to user claims or rights instead of monolithic user roles
For many sites, profile or other non-traditional information is very important and needs to come from somewhere other than an API call that maps to a database blob
What would work a lot better here is a system in which you were able to define your users, rights, and other attributes however you wanted and the membership system worked with your model - not the other way around.

You can't retrieve passwords with SimpleMembership, but you can let the user reset them. There is no workaround.

You must use some other membership provider, such as the standard SqlMembershipProvider, which may also not allow you to retrieve a password in clear text.

The days of retrieving a password in clear text is over, as this is a major security risk if it ends up in the wrong hands.

Hope this clears up some of your thinking about what you wish to achieve.

Some reading:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

[Migrating from ASP.NET Membership to SimpleMembership in MVC4 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236533/migrating-from-asp-net-membership-to-simplemembership-in-mvc4-rtm)

http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/

Comment: thanks for the links.. I agree with retrieving passwords.  This is just another case of working with an existing application. I am moving it all away from the plain text passwords.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleMembership does not allow you to choose the password format.

Comment: that would explain why i'm having such a hard time finding it but how do you know this. I mean where is there anything talking about this change...

Comment: @TimLint - Where is there anything talking much about SimpleMembership at all?  There's very little documentation on it.  ALmost everything is hard coded in SimpleMembership.  You can check out the source yourself.  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/50c07799ae48#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs

Comment: Agreed.. I am finding bit by bit everything I need. My app is running smoothly and I am LOVING simple membership really. Its just so simple (no pun intended) and easy to track your own data without extending and implementing the cumbersome bloated membershipprovider

Comment: @TimLint/@Erik - I would really appreciate if you could help me out. I want to recover (decrypt) a password stored in SimpleMembership. Is that possible?

Comment: @ilanS Using simple membership you can choose where and how to store the password. if it is stored in a table as plain text (not recommended) you can retrieve it.  I have done this before with applications that don't require much security. Many applications now build in ways to reset instead of retrieve this info. This is definitely a more secure method.

Comment: The problem I had was that I wanted a different partners application to login remotely to my app... So recovering the password would have helped. Or even knowing how to encrypt the user and password to get the same key. But where is the key? And how to encrypt exactly like the membership? I didn't find real answers.