# Retrieve a single row and column with nhibernate and convert it to a string

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am creating a login function in MVC 4.0 with a Salt. The Salt is constant for each registered user, because the security doesn't have to be top-notch. Now to create the hash (to compare with the hash in the database) I need to retrieve the salt for the specific user from the DB and with the password which has been inserted create the hash. I use Nhibernate for database trafic. Yet, since I'm fairly new to Nhibernate, I don't know how to retrieve the salt as a string, I tried this:

```
 var salt = session.QueryOver<Translator>()
     .Where(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress)
     .Select(x => x.Salt)
     .List()
     .ToString();
```

Where the x. is the mapping and `emailAddress` is a parameter in the function.
The error mentions that the salt value (it actually shows the string) is not of type models.translator and cannot be used in this generic collection.

Comment: Why don't u use the default SimpleMembership with salt password?

Comment: I kinda have this assignment where i have to use certain options, like encrypting to pbkdf2 for the hash.. SimpleMembership doesnt cover that right?

Comment: Note that in MVC 4 and ASP.NET 4 and 4.5 the default hash is now HMACSHA256.

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236533/migrating-from-asp-net-membership-to-simplemembership-in-mvc4-rtm

Comment: Yes, but nevertheless I am kinda stuck with the things I have to use for the assignment.. Wish I could go with the easy solution

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that expensive to fetch the entire entity and then get it's `.Salt` property, so you can safely forget about the `Select` part.

In the criteria API, however, I know that you can use `.SetProjection()` on the query to get a single property and then call `.UniqueResult<string>()`.

With `QueryOver`, you could try `.List<string>()`. Do not call `.ToString()` on a list though, but instead get the only element of the list with `.Single()`.

Comment: Yup, `List<string>` (or `SingleOrDefault<string>`, if it's a single entry) should be fine. LINQ provider can also be used to get the same result.

Comment: Hmm, these pieces seem to solve the puzzle when I read up about them, but I have a little trouble creating the proper syntax to complete the puzzle.. Any chance you could give me an example?

Comment: There is an official example here, the 3rd one in the paragraph: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-querystructure . So instead of your .List().ToString(), I suspect it to be .List<string>().Single(), or even .Single<string>() as @Patryk suggested. Change Single to SingleOrDefault if it's possible that there are no rows.

Comment: Yeah I saw that example and tried it, apparantly the problem doesnt lie with this syntax but somewhere else, since the error I am getting shows the salt string I wanted to retrieve from the database perfectly fine, but it can't seem to be used in this generic collection.. Though, I cant figure out what that means..