# MembershipProvider & SimpleMembership (MVC4 Internet App template)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm doing a side-by-side migration of a pretty large existing WebForms app to MVC 4.  The app currently uses the MembershipProvider mechanism to do auth.  How can I use MembershipProvider side-by-side with the newer SimpleMembership that is included in the ASP.NET MVC 4 "Internet Application" project template?  It's not possible to change it all over at once since the app will take several months to convert completely and therefore the side-by-side migration.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12236533/156611), I'm guessing the answer is "not possible" or "strongly not advised" but I thought I'd ask anyways.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the same thing. `SimpleMembership` is *itself* a `MembershipProvider`. Basically, the site you're converting has its own customized membership setup. Most likely you *couldn't* actually convert it, because it would still require making cutomizations to `SimpleMembership` which would simply net you another custom `MembershipProvider`.

Besides, ASP.NET MVC5 is already out, and with it, ASP.NET Identity, which completely replaces the old membership system. So, if you're going to spend the time to switch out your authentication, you might as well go for the latest and greatest, instead of moving from one outdated system to another.

Comment: So it sounds like I should either take the plunge and convert all existing WebForms pages to support Identity or continue to use the existing MembershipProvider.  Not wanting to mess with existing WebForms pages, I think I'll keep the status quo for now.  Once the entire app is MVC, converting to Identity will be more straight-forward, not to mention it gives Microsoft some time to release an SP for Identity.

Comment: Well, not a service pack, per se, but an upgrade to the Nuget. They've already done that a few times already, though. Identity is at 2.0 now, and from what I've seen is pretty feature complete. I wouldn't hold off just because it's "new", but yeah, it's going to be a non-trivial upgrade.